# Javascript Loop to Create Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to make a lease calculator that accepts one input and outputs 4 options **(24, 36, 48, 60)** months based on different rates for each term. I can do it all without a loop, but can't seem to figure out how to use the `toFixed(2)` within the code. So, I tried using loops to loop through the input * rates. Then I added another loop to use to `toFixed` function, then another loop to create the output. Thinking I need each loop to create an array that I can use for the next one. I'm a noob so be easy on me. I'm sure this is an easy prob for most everyone here.  Here's what I have so far:

```
Function calculateTotal()
{    
"use strict";   
var theForm = document.forms["leaseCalc"];
var tec = document.getElementById("tec").value;  
var rates = [0.0477, 0.0329, 0.0256, 0.0212];
var months = [24, 36, 48, 60];

var monthlyPayments = 0;
for (var i=0; i < rates.length; i++) { 
    monthlyPayments += (tec * rates[i]);
}   
var formatTwo = 0;
for (var i=0; i < monthlyPayments.length; i++) {
    formatTwo += monthlyPayments.toFixed(2);
}
var results = 0;    
for (var i=0; i < months.length; i++) { 
    results += "<p>" + months[i] + " months = $" + formatTwo[i] + "</p>";
        alert(results);
}
```

Comment: What are examples of expected input and current vs. expected output?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do all three loops.
as the arrays are the same size just iterate over the months and use that index to access the other arrays:

```
var tec = document.getElementById("tec").value;  
var rates = [0.0477, 0.0329, 0.0256, 0.0212];
var months = [24, 36, 48, 60];

var results = '';    
for (var i=0; i < months.length; i++) { 
    results += "<p>" + months[i] + " months = $" + (tec * rates[i]).toFixed(2) + "</p>";
}

alert(results);
```